# Can not verify contract on etherscan.io “Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI”

Tags: solidity, etherscan, abi, bytecode, error

I am getting the error

> "Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI"

When I try to verify this code. I have split it into two pieces as I import it but not sure how to include it all in etherscan.io

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import "./VeteranCoinInterface.sol";


contract VeteranCoin is VeteranCoinInterface {

    uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;
    /*
    NOTE:
    The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
    They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
    Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
    */
    string public name = "Veteran Coin";                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
    uint8 public decimals = 8;                //How many decimals to show.
    string public symbol = "VET";
    uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy = 5000;     // How many units of your coin can be bought by 1 ETH?
    uint256 public totalEthInWei;         // WEI is the smallest unit of ETH (the equivalent of cent in USD or satoshi in BTC). We'll store the total ETH raised via our ICO here.  
    address public fundsWallet =0x199316D9b0eDe0BF61a6b855e817D4D679D8B321;//An identifier: eg SBX

    function VeteranCoin(
    ) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = 1000000 * 100000000 ;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = 1000000 * 100000000;                        // Update total supply
        name = "VeteranCoin";                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        decimals = 8;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        symbol = "VET";
        unitsOneEthCanBuy = 5000;                                      // Set the price of your token for the ICO (CHANGE THIS)
        fundsWallet =0x199316D9b0eDe0BF61a6b855e817D4D679D8B321;                   // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        }
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }   
     function() payable{
        totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;
        uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;
        if (balances[fundsWallet] < amount) {
            return;
        }

        balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;

        Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount); // Broadcast a message to the blockchain

        //Transfer ether to fundsWallet
        fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
    }                               

}
```

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;


contract VeteranCoinInterface {
    /* This is a slight change to the ERC20 base standard.
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply);
    is replaced with:
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    This automatically creates a getter function for the totalSupply.
    This is moved to the base contract since public getter functions are not
    currently recognised as an implementation of the matching abstract
    function by the compiler.
    */
    /// total amount of tokens
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance);

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_spender` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of tokens to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining);

    // solhint-disable-next-line no-simple-event-func-name  
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value); 
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a tool like https://github.com/BlockCatIO/solidity-flattener to consolidate your sources in a single file. It will replace imports with the content of the imported file.

In your case a command line similar to this should work

```
solidity_flattener --output VeteranCoinFlattened.sol VeteranCoin.sol
```